# Spring Data R2DBC - Building custom postgresql query in reactive repository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-el, spring-data-r2dbc

I have a table that contains entities with a String id, String jobId, and String status.  Given a jobId and a List of ids, I would like to query that table and return a Flux of ids that are not present in the database.

I can do this successfully if I manually execute the following query in pgadmin:

```
SELECT a.id FROM (VALUES ('20191001_182447_1038'),('abc'),('fdjk')) AS a(id) LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM items WHERE job_id = '10a7a04a-aa67-499a-83eb-0cd3625fe27a') b ON a.id = b.id WHERE b.id IS null
```

The response comes back with only the ids that are not present, 'abc' and 'fdjk'.

In my spring data repo, I define the following method:

```
    @Query("SELECT a.id FROM (VALUES (:ids)) AS a(id) LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM items WHERE job_id = :jobId) b ON a.id = b.id WHERE b.id IS null")
    Flux<ItemId> getNotContains(@Param("jobId") String jobId, @Param("ids") Collection<String> ids);
```

The problem is, when I run the code, the query gets expanded to:

```
SELECT a.id FROM (VALUES ($1, $2, $3)) AS a(id) LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM items WHERE job_id = $251) b ON a.id = b.id WHERE b.id IS null]
```

This always returns a single value because the values are being grouped into a single set of parenthesis instead of wrapping each element of my collection in parenthesis.  Just curious if there is a way to handle this properly.

EDIT
Entity class is:

```
@Data
@Table("items")
public class Item implements Persistable {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String jobId;
    private String customerId;
    private Date queuedDate;
    private Date lastUpdated;
    private String destination;
    private String type;
    private Status status;
}
```

Also, my repo is:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends R2dbcRepository<Item, String>
```

R2dbcRepository doesn't currently support the fancy magic of more mature spring data repos, so you can't do things like `findByJobId` and have it auto-gen the query for you.

Comment: instead of `(:ids)` just use `:ids` in the @Query. Can you share your entity class. May be there is a way you can do it without `@Query`

Comment: Did you try this `findByJobIdAndItemIdNotIn(@Param("jobId") String jobId, @Param("ids") List<String> ids)`?

Comment: Thanks @pvpkiran - removing the parentheses from :ids was part of the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enforce parenthesis by wrapping your arguments into a `Object[]` to render parameters as expression list.

```
interface MyRepo {
    @Query(…)
    Flux<ItemId> getNotContains(@Param("jobId") String jobId, @Param("ids") Collection<Object[]> ids);
}

MyRepo myRepo = …;
Collection<Object[]> ids = Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"1"}, new Object[]{"2"});

myRepo.getNotContains("foo", ids);
```

See also:

- [`NamedParameterUtils` Javadoc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/blob/929c4dfab4b47f9af895570e92fd0cbf78002929/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/r2dbc/core/NamedParameterUtils.java#L252)

Comment: Thanks! I know see it expanding with with parenthesis around each value so that gets me much closer, however now it returns 0 results.  I also tried it with String[] instead of Object[] -- no luck. Is there a way to see the _actual_ statement being executed, with the real values populated in the statement? Setting org.springframework.data and io.r2dbc to DEBUG still doesn't seem to show it.

Comment: Use logging categories of Spring Data (org.springfrsmework.data)

Comment: This ended up working after I also implemented the suggestion from @pvpkiran to remove the parentheses from :ids